# Get last 3 records

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to get the last 3 records (red border)? Please check the screenshot.

Screenshot:
[image]

MySQL query.

```
SELECT icm_external_data.client_id,
            icm_external_data.gsheet_tab AS source,
            icm_external_data.type,
            icm_external_data.name AS lead_name,
            COUNT(DISTINCT icm_leads.email) AS on_month_leads,
            date_format(icm_leads.date_created,'%M') AS month,
            date_format(icm_leads.date_created,'%Y') AS YEAR,
            @running_total := @running_total + COUNT(DISTINCT icm_leads.email) AS cumulative_sum
        FROM icm_leads
        LEFT JOIN icm_external_data ON icm_external_data.gsheet_id = icm_leads.gsheet_id
        JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
    WHERE icm_external_data.id = '29'
    AND icm_leads.gsheet_id = 'xxx'
    AND (icm_leads.tab_name = 'xxx' OR icm_leads.tab_name = 'xxx')
    AND icm_leads.email NOT LIKE '%xxx%'
    AND (icm_leads.`type` = 'forms' OR icm_leads.`type` = 'calls')
GROUP BY year(icm_leads.date_created),month(icm_leads.date_created)
```

Comment: Your screen shot highlights the last three complete months, rather than the last three records, which is what your question says. Which is it?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular sorry. Yes, you are correct sir. It's last 3 months instead but will not include the current month which is May. Next month is June, so I should get March, April, May. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` keywords.

```
SELECT icm_external_data.client_id,
            icm_external_data.gsheet_tab AS source,
            icm_external_data.type,
            icm_external_data.name AS lead_name,
            COUNT(DISTINCT icm_leads.email) AS on_month_leads,
            date_format(icm_leads.date_created,'%M') AS month,
            date_format(icm_leads.date_created,'%Y') AS YEAR,
            @running_total := @running_total + COUNT(DISTINCT icm_leads.email) AS cumulative_sum
        FROM icm_leads
        LEFT JOIN icm_external_data ON icm_external_data.gsheet_id = icm_leads.gsheet_id
        JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
    WHERE icm_external_data.id = '29'
    AND icm_leads.gsheet_id = 'xxx'
    AND (icm_leads.tab_name = 'xxx' OR icm_leads.tab_name = 'xxx')
    AND icm_leads.email NOT LIKE '%xxx%'
    AND (icm_leads.`type` = 'forms' OR icm_leads.`type` = 'calls')
GROUP BY year(icm_leads.date_created),month(icm_leads.date_created)
ORDER BY icm_leads.date_created DESC
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 1
```

Comment: I don't think that will quite do it. The screenshot indicates that he wants the last three complete months, rather than the last three records, which is what the question says.

Comment: Sorry my fault. You are correct last 3 months instead but will not include the current month which is May. Next month is June, so I should get March, April, May. 

Thank you so much.

Comment: edited to add `OFFSET 1` which should ignore the last row in your picture, or the first row when it's ordered

Comment: @Joshua it should be Feb, Mar, Apr.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
order by min(icm_leads.date_created) desc
limit 3 offset 1
```